# XSLT Convert generic XML

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file generated using `javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet.writeXml` which looks like:

```
<metadata>
This section has column properties like name / label etc
</metadata>
<data>
<currentRow>
      <columnValue>Ken</columnValue>
      <columnValue>12</columnValue>
      <columnValue>USA</columnValue>
    </currentRow>
</data>
```

I want to convert this to look like:

```
<Class>
     <Student>
      <name>Ken</name>
      <ID>12</ID>
      <location>USA</location>
    </Student>
</Class>
```

How can I do the conversion? I need this to transform the XML to a HTML table.

Comment: So there's only one `currentRow` element, and multiple `columnValue` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Class>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/data/currentRow" />
        </Class>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="currentRow">
        <Student>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="columnValue" />
        </Student>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="columnValue[1]">
        <name><xsl:apply-templates/></name>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="columnValue[2]">
        <ID><xsl:apply-templates/></ID>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="columnValue[3]">
        <location><xsl:apply-templates/></location>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** Added a root node to the given source to make it well-formed.